# CSS Responsive Bootstrap DIV Height

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12" id="header">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span10" id="body">
            </div>
            <div class="span2">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12" id="updates">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span12" id="chat">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my code for the basic structure that I dynamically fill with JQuery on the load. I want the 2nd row-fluid to never exceed the page height also I never want my page to have y-scrollbars to appear. Kindly guide me with the css.

Comment: And how do you want to reach the content if there is not enough space on the screen ?

Comment: scroll within the div.body, div.chats.

Comment: what is the max-width of the page? 1280px, 1024px, 768px, 320px?  For this kind of layout I set a max-width and then throw floats out the window and go with absolute (or fixed if your more apt).  Anytime I see more than one scroll bar on a wireframe I instantly go to absolute positioning.  You can check into flex, not sure how well they will handle multiple scrollable areas.

Answer (score 0):

Your y scroll bar is depend on the data you fill into the `row-fluid`. to remove the scroll bar you can apply style.

```
max-height:500px;
overflow:hidden;
```

to your second `row-fluid`.

but the extra content will be hidden.

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/8zznn/)  fiddle.

Comment: using 500px for height, will make the page unresponsive. no? is there no way I can let the page response to the screen height and extend the container div to screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's hard to regenerate your interface without your CSS and Jquery, I assume you need the height not to be exceed the browser view port height. You can specify the right panel to a separate class i.e `.right-panel` and put it max-height with CSS3 `vh`values. So it would look like:

```
.right-panel{
height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope that helps.